# Confusion regarding the Susskind-Uglum conjecture

Tags: entropy, quantum-entanglement, renormalization, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I have a very basic confusion regarding entropies in holography. In AdS/CFT, the Susskind-Uglum conjecture states that the generalized entropy of a bulk region, given by

$$S_{\text{gen}}(A) = \frac{\text{area}(A)}{4G_N} + S_{\text{vN}}(A),$$

is UV finite, where $S_{\text{vN}}(A)$ is the von Neumann entropy of the quantum fields in the subregion $A$. In particular, it is claimed that the UV divergences of the area term cancel the UV divergences in the von Neumann entropy term. But at least naively (and perhaps this is my mistake), both of these quantities are non-negative. If I used some regulator $\Lambda$ to compute these quantities, then that would suggest, for example, that

$$S_{\text{gen}, \Lambda} \geq \frac{\text{area}(A)}{4G_{N, \Lambda}} \quad \text{for all }\Lambda,$$

where the $\Lambda$ in the subscript denotes the regularized quantity. Thus, in the limit that we take $\Lambda\to \infty$, $S_\text{gen}$ must blow up if the area term does (or by the same reasoning if the von Neumann entropy does). This apparent contradiction seems much too simple to not have an obvious flaw in reasoning, but I embarrassingly do not know what it is. Any help or direction to references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your question boils down to: if $A = B + C$, and $B$ and $C$ are both positive, then what does it mean for the "divergences to cancel"? Because divergences (typically) only cancel if one thing is positive and the other is negative. Do you have a source for the claim about the divergences? I wouldn't mind reading up on it.

Comment: Indeed that's all there is to it! There are several places in the literature that make reference to the claim, for example, appendix A of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02669.pdf. They show there that since all divergences of the entropy have the same form as the grav counter terms, S_gen can be made finite with a suitable renormalization. But it does not address the issue of sign to which I'm alluding...